# html 5 simultaneous audio playback - AudioGroups

Tags: html

How can you play 2 or more files at the exact same starting position with straight up HTML5?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to, yes, although not on iOS which I believe currently only allows one (this is by design according to Apple).

Comment: Hi Ian. How would you do this? Would you have to rig it to work like an audiogroup (like in AS3)? Or is there an audio group function?

Comment: I know nothing about AS3, but can't you just start them all at the same time?